# Изменение размера шрифта при Duplicate Group

Tags: дизайн, веб-дизайн, photoshop

Имеется группа с элементов, в том числе и текст, после `Duplicate Group` в другой документ я изменяю высоту и ширину. Допустим, в 3 раза, т.е 300 процентов, должен измениться и размер шрифта, но значения остаются прежними, хотя фактически размер изменился. Как это исправить, чтобы указывался правильный размер?